# How to validate specific data in an object(Vee-validate) and show custom error message?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How to validate specific data in an object in vee-validate?
I just want to validate first name and last name in an object then show custom error message, because I'm using naming convention.

I want to validate first and last name when clicking submit.

```
data() {
      return {
         per: {
            strFirst: '',
            strMiddle: '',
            strLast: ''
         }
      }
```

[Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/3uec1exm/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you might need to overwrite the error messages, or add new ones. The Validator class and its instances provide an updateDictionary method. which will merge the messages with the internal dictionary, overwriting any duplicates.

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';
const dictionary = {
  en: {
    messages:{
      alpha: () => 'Some English Message'
    }
  },
  ar: {
    messages: {
      alpha: () => 'Some Arabic Message'
    }
  }
};

Validator.updateDictionary(dictionary);

const validator = new Validator({ first_name: 'alpha' });

validator.setLocale('ar'); // now this validator will generate messages in arabic.
```

Here's link of vee-validate plugin  - http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/rules.html#custom-messages